# Pivot multiple columns sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a stored proc / sql returning datatable as below:

```
today_date  prev_date   sales   Company     S  itmgrp   itemName    sales
3/16/2015   3/13/2015   Online  CompanyA    S1  Personal    P - D   -3391.17
3/16/2015   3/13/2015   Online  CompanyA    S1  Home    MIS - D 286.2294316
3/16/2015   3/13/2015   Online  CompanyA    S1  Home    M L - D 240.3000802
3/16/2015   3/13/2015   Online  CompanyA    S1  Home    P - D   -313.0786364
3/16/2015   3/13/2015   Online  CompanyA    S1  Home    M L - D -3096.968552
3/16/2015   3/13/2015   Online  CompanyA    S1  Home    P L - D -5567.942955
3/16/2015   3/13/2015   Online  CompanyA    S2  Home    PC  -8770.911724
3/16/2015   3/13/2015   Online  CompanyA    S3  Personal    PJ  -808.36
3/16/2015   3/13/2015   Online  CompanyA    S3  Home    PJ  -42800.9843
3/16/2015   3/13/2015   Online  CompanyA    S3  Home    PJ  1760.708018
3/16/2015   3/13/2015   Online  CompanyA    S4  Home    PGF - D -59011.18629
3/16/2015   3/13/2015   Online  CompanyA    S1  Home    P - D   -560.2475234
```

How do I use PIVOT of SQL Server to have pivot result in below format:

Rows:   Company/itemgroup/itemName 
Values: sum(sales)

```
CompanyA    
 Personal   
   P - D    -3391.17
   PJ       -808.36
 Home   
   P - D    -873.3261597
   MIS - D  286.2294316
   M L - D  -2856.668472
   P L - D  -5567.942955
   PC       -8770.911724
   PJ       -41040.27628
   PGF - D  -59011.18629
```

I can get distinct values for Company/itemgroup/itemName

All examples I have seen so far seem to be single column pivot.

Comment: Even with your edit it's not clear to me how you want the data to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something very similar with `group by rollup` and then filtering by `grouping_id()`:

```
with x as (
select company, itmgrp, itemname, sum(sales_amt) as sales_amt, grouping_id(company) as company_gid, grouping_id(itmgrp) as itmgrp_gid, grouping_id(itemname) as itemname_gid
from #t
group by rollup(company, itmgrp, itemname)
)
select 
case when itmgrp_gid = 1 then company else null end,
case when itemname_gid = 1 then itmgrp else null end,
itemname,
case when company_gid + itmgrp_gid + itemname_gid = 0 then sales_amt else null end
from x
where company_gid + itmgrp_gid + itemname_gid < 3
order by company, itmgrp, itemname, company_gid, itmgrp_gid, itemname_gid
```

Comment: grouping_id isn't  a function with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @buffer_overflow: [I wouldn't be so sure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510624%28v=sql.100%29.aspx "GROUPING_ID (Transact-SQL)"). Anyway, what you are trying to do is a presentation issue. SQL Server should only provide you with data and it's the presentation layer that should do the formatting. Usually it's a job for a reporting tool.